# Rails 4 Restaurant order system ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ItemsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am creating a simple restaurant ordering system with a one to many relationship between a menu and its items. One menu has many items. For the sake of simplicity it is not a many to many.

I am able to create menus fine, but would like to be able to add and show the menu items for that menu in the menus show action.

The menu show action displays okay but when I try to add a new menu item I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ItemsController#create
Couldn't find Menu with 'id'=
raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{name} with '#{primary_key}'=#{id}"
```

And here is the queries from the terminal:

```
Started POST "/items" for ::1 at 2015-01-11 16:09:44 +0000
Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***", "item"=>{"name"=>"Test",     "price"=>"23", "course"=>"Main", "vegetarian"=>"1", "allergy"=>""}, "commit"=>"Add item"}
  Menu Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `menus`.* FROM `menus` WHERE `menus`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 8ms
```

EDIT: I followed doon's advice and looked into nested resources and this is indeed a better way of doing it. The updated code is below:

### routes.rb

```
resources :menus do
  resources :items
end
```

### menus_controller.rb

```
def show
  @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
  @items = @menu.items
end
```

### items_controller.rb

```
def create
  @menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
  @item = @menu.items.create!(item_params)
  if @item.save
    flash[:success] = "Item added!"
    redirect_to @menu
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Errors found!"
    redirect_to @menu
  end
end

private
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :price, :course, :vegetarian, :allergy, :menu_id)
  end
```

And the Menus

### show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "<< Back", menus_path, data: { confirm: back_message } %>

<h1><%= @menu.name %> menu</h1>

<center><button id="toggleButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Show/Hide Add Item Form</button></center>
<br>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 toggleDiv hideDiv">
    <%= form_for [@menu, Item.new] do |f| %>
      <table class="table table-condensed table-no-border">
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="col-xs-2">Name:</th>
          <td class="col-xs-10"><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Price:</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field :price %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Course:</th>
          <td><%= f.select(:course, options_for_select([['Starter', 'Starter'], ['Main', 'Main'], ['Dessert', 'Dessert'], ['Drink', 'Drink']]), prompt:     "Please select...", class: 'form-control') %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Vegetarian:</th>
          <td><%= f.check_box :vegetarian %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Allergy:</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field :allergy %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><%= f.submit "Add item", class: "btn btn-sm btn-success col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" %></td></tr>
      </table>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Vegetarian</th>
      <th>Allergy</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(item.price, unit: "£") %></td>
        <td><%= item.course %></td>
        <td><%= item.vegetarian %></td>
        <td><%= item.allergy %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would probably do in a case like this (especially if your item doesn't exist outside of a menu) is to use Nested Resources:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources (a bit dated, but still a decent grounding)

Below are some changes to get you pointed in this direction.

**config/routes.rb**

```
 resources :menu do 
    resources :items
 end
```

now our urls will look like

```
 /menu/:menu_id/items/
```

So we need to adjust the items_controller to get the menu by looking at `:menu_id`, and we don't need the hidden field anymore.  I put it in a `before_action` as every method in the controller will build through the association.

**items_controller.rb**

```
 class ItemsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :find_menu 

   ...

   def create
      @item = @menu.items.new(item_params)
      if @item.save
        redirect_to @menu, notice: 'item added'
      else
        redirect_to @menu, warning: 'item failed'
      end
   end

   ...
   private

   def find_menu
     @menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
   end
 end
```

if you want to show it on the menu, we need a new Item to display.

**menus_controller.rb**

```
   def show
     @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
     @item = @menu.items.new  
   end
```

Then we need to make use of the nested resource in the `menus/show`  view. By passing in the array of the menu and the item,  rails will generate the correct path.

**menus/show.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for [@menu,@item]  do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting to "/post" or "post/[:id]"?

```
@menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
```

Will not find anything if you do not pass it an id. The id can come from the URL params, but this means you should be sending your request to "/post/[:menuid].

You can use the gem https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors to debug your program at the controller level and execute rails console there. just put in "fail" in your controller and then you will have a command line interface where you can inspect your params value and ensure it has the id included and play with the console there.

Comment: So I have run better_errors and got an issue where Item couldn't be nil on first item, so I added `@item = Item.new` in the show action of Menus and `@items = @menu.items.all` which I am hoping will show the all the items for that specific menu. @menu in the items controller is nil. How would I pass the menu id in the post?

Comment: You probably do not want to "build" any items in the show action, as then you are creating and not showing. Your show action can be like @menu = Menu.includes(:items).find(params[:id]) this will load the menu and its items in one SQL Query. Then you should be able to iterate as you are doing "<% (at)menu.items.each do |item| %>". At this point is the POST action working and the new problem is in the show view? It seems like you've made some progress since your original post.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved it. Thanks to better_errors I was able to better understand what was going on.

I implemented the show action in menus_controller.rb from aaron.

```
def show
  @item = Item.new
  @menu = Menu.includes(:items).find(params[:id])
end
```

I needed a way to pass the menu id into the menu_id field, so I added a hidden field in the table or show.html.erb passing the current @menu.id into the :menu_id field.
`<%= f.hidden_field :menu_id, :value => @menu.id %>`

I have read online that passing values through hidden fields is not a great idea though.

Then in the create action of the Items Controller I was able to make a new record as usual redirecting to the existing show view using the menu id from the item object.

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  if @item.save
    redirect_to menu_path(@item.menu_id)
  else
    redirect_to menu_path(@menu.menu_id)
  end
end
```

It feels like a bit of a hack so open to suggestions on how to improve.

Comment: You might look at nesting items under menu. Especially if menu has many items.